# unexpeced token: ( with dynamic SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

The following gives an error on runtime:

```
String queryString = 'select name,street_address__c from warehouse__c where' +
    'DISTANCE(location__c,GEOLOCATION('+
    lat + ',' + lon+
    ' ),\'mi\') <'+distance;
results = Database.Query(queryString);
```

The error message says

> unexpeced token: (

The error goes away if the comment the second line. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the error. Corrected it to:

String queryString = 'Select Id, name ' + 'from warehouse__c ' + 
 'where distance(location__c, GEOLOCATION('+lat+','+lon+'), \'mi\') < 20 ' + 
        'limit 10';

Comment: just a space between where and distance was missing :)